# Changing calendar event color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'd like to be able to programmatically change the color of calendar events. I was going through this documentation, but don't understand what the "key" is referring to here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors. Is it the event ID?

I'd also like to know if it's possible to change a calendar event color via a spreadsheet. I have a script to add entries from a spreadsheet to a calendar, but I want to be able to define the colors as well. Please point me to helpful reading material or examples if possible.

Edit 12/20/2015- added working script to add events:

```
function createEvent() {
var calendarId = 'MY_ID';
var event = {
summary: 'test',
description: 'test desc',
"end": {
"date": "2015-12-21"
},
"start": {
"date": "2015-12-21"
},
colorId: 10
};
event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

Comment: if you want to make it simpler, have a look at this example I wrote with Romain Vialard : https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar/calendar_edit_example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, are you confused by Google's lack of documentation on this? Don't worry, so was I. [Here's](http://www.voindo.eu/2012/06/11/google-calendar-api-v3-set-color-color-chart/) a chart of the numbers (keys) and the associated colors. Looks something like this in the end:

```
var event = {
    summary: "Summarizing",
    description: "Descriptive",
    start: {
      date: Utilities.formatDate(start, "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    },
    end: {
      date: Utilities.formatDate(end, "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    },
    colorId: 10
  };
  event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId); 
 }
```

Hope that helps! For the second part: It should be possible, just make sure you're using the Google Calendar Advanced service. Without more detail about what you're trying to do, it's hard to provide more info :/

Comment: Ah, so key is colorID- got it, thanks! I am getting an error that I think is because calendar advanced service is not enabled, even though I enabled it. I ran a test to see if I could set color ID (included script in body of main post). Any idea why I am getting this error "Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,object,object,object). (line 3, file "Code")"

Comment: Well, if you want to set the color of the event you're creating the more important issue is that you are using the CalendarApp method, rather than the Advanced Calendar Service, documentation at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar - unfortunately, (to my knowledge) there is no way to create a colored event using the CalendarApp. As for your error, the advanced parameters should be in one object, not split apart - not sure if that's the cause of the error, but it would stop the code from executing.

Comment: if you want to make it simpler, have a look at this example I wrote with Romain Vialard : https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar/calendar_edit_example

Comment: Thank you but I am also doing this as an exercise in learning to work with Google apps script and js.

Comment: you are perfectly right ! it was just in case... for lazy programmers ;-)

Comment: this worked for me as well. any idea how to do background event color vs foreground text color? because ever since the new calendar update (maybe a few weeks ago), before, my events were colored, but now it's just a text that's colored with the event white....

Answer (score 1):

For quick reference I thought I'd chip in and reference Google's [ColorEnum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color)  documentation as well as list off the available calendar colors here:

```json
 1 Pale Blue
 2 Pale Green
 3 Mauve
 4 Pale Red
 5 Yellow
 6 Orange
 7 Cyan
 8 Gray
 9 Blue
10 Green
11 Red
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but in case someone is looking for some sample code.
The below code has all the information stored in a spreadsheet:

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet Name")
var index = 2;
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

for (;index <= lastRow; index++){
var title = sheet.getRange(index, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
var startTime = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
var endTime = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
var description = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
var location = sheet.getRange(index, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
var guests = sheet.getRange(index, 6, 1, 1).getValue();
var eventColour = sheet.getRange(index, 7, 1, 1).getValue();
var sendInvites = true;

var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("your Calendar ID").createEvent(title, startTime, endTime,
{description: description, location: location, guests: guests, sendInvites: sendInvites }).getId();

if (eventColour === "Condition1") CalendarApp.getEventById(calendar).setColor("10")
if (eventColour === "Condition2") CalendarApp.getEventById(calendar).setColor("11")
if (eventColour === "Condition3") CalendarApp.getEventById(calendar).setColor("12")
if (eventColour === "Condition4") CalendarApp.getEventById(calendar).setColor("13")


}// End of For Loop
}// End of Function
```